# What does CommonReference used by Readable in Range-v3 do?

Tags: c++, range-v3

I found that `typename gsl::span<const gsl::byte>::const_iterator` doesn't satisfy `Readable` concept in range-v3. After looking through the concept, I found this constraint:

```
template<typename I>
            auto requires_(I&&) -> decltype(
                concepts::valid_expr(
                    // The value, reference and rvalue reference types are related
                    // through the CommonReference concept.
                    concepts::model_of<CommonReference, reference_t<I> &&, value_t<I> &>(),
                    concepts::model_of<CommonReference, reference_t<I> &&, rvalue_reference_t<I> &&>(),
                    concepts::model_of<CommonReference, rvalue_reference_t<I> &&, value_t<I> const &>(),
                    // Experimental additional tests. If nothing else, this is a good workout
                    // for the common_reference code.
                    concepts::model_of<Same, ranges::common_reference_t<reference_t<I>, value_t<I>>, value_t<I>>(),
                    concepts::model_of<Same, ranges::common_reference_t<rvalue_reference_t<I>, value_t<I>>, value_t<I>>()
                ));
```

`ranges::common_reference_t` removes the `const` from the `value_type` and then they are not same.

What do the `CommonReference` constraints mean? Why should `Readable` satisfy them?

Comment: `Readable` is satisfied by things that look like pointers (like iterators and smart pointers). A `span` is not pointer-like. It's more like a `Range`. I think you're using the wrong concept to constrain `span`.

Comment: And for the record, those last two "experimental" `Same` constraints have been removed in the latest range-v3 release. You should update.

Comment: @EricNiebler Sorry, my mistake. I mean decltype(span.cbegin()) doesn't satify `Readable`.

Comment: @EricNiebler Unfortunately, it seems that the Microsoft fork of range-v3 is old... By the way, what's the relationship between "looking like pointers" and `CommonReference`?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in the GSL. From the source for `span_iterator` (https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL/blob/master/gsl/span#L145-L147):

`using value_type =
    std::conditional_t<IsConst, std::add_const_t<typename Span::element_type>,
                       typename Span::element_type>;`

So `span::const_iterator` has a `const`-qualified `value_type`. That's weird and wrong. It's probably also not standard conforming. I have yet to find definitive proof within the standard for that assertion, but the standard is highly suggestive. For instance, here is the specialization of `std::iterator_traits` for pointers to const:

`template<class T> struct iterator_traits<const T*> {
  using difference_type = ptrdiff_t;
  using value_type = T;
  using pointer = const T*;
  using reference = const T&;
  using iterator_category = random_access_iterator_tag;
};`

See? `value_type` is not `const`-qualified, even for pointers-to-`const`.

Comment: This is now fixed in the GSL.